# What do the links 'Newsfeed One Drive Sites' come from?

Tags: my-site, site-template

When accessing a MySite in Sharepoint 2013, those three links appear at the top on the page.  Are they hardcoded values in .ascx controls or are they derived somewhere from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links are hard-coded, provided by a delegate control.  If you want to change them, you would need to override the delegate control.  I have a blog post about how to do this here: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2013-adding-links-suite-bar-newsfeed-skydrive-sites-overriding-suitelinksdelegate-delegate-control/